# Echo to a variable from a file

Tags: regex, bash, list, sed

I do have a list with components that look like this:

`file.txt`:

```
example-component-test 1.0.0 [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
response-enricher 1.1.2 [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
example-another-component 1.0.0 [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
```

At the moment I extract the name of the component and the version from the file with these commands:

```sh
component=`echo file.txt | sed 's/\S*\s*\(.*\)/\1/'`
```

What I would like to do, is that the name also contains the environment, so `file.txt` will look like this:

```
example-component-test 1.0.0 [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
response-enricher 1.1.2 [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
example-another-component 1.0.0 [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
```

I need a `sed` command in order to extract that last part. `[dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net`

Thank you.

Comment: Is `[dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net` in your file.txt, or do you want to add it to each line in that file?

Comment: is it in that file

Comment: Then update your question so your sample file.txt contents includes it?

Comment: And maybe explain more what you're trying to do with the values in the file, so we can give a better answer?

Comment: just need to add them in a variable like the previous one.  component=echo file.txt | sed 's/\S*\s*\(.*\)/\1/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read) bash builtin to read each line of the file and save it as shell variables (Using the [`IFS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html#index-IFS) shell variable to control where to [split the line up](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting)):

```
while IFS=" " read -r package version env; do
    echo "package $package version $version uses $env"
done < file.txt
```

This produces:

```
package example-component-test version 1.0.0 uses [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
package response-enricher version 1.1.2 uses [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
package example-another-component version 1.0.0 uses [dev1] chld78269.ch.test.net
```

from your example file.